# SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

I have created a Database Project in Visual Studio 2010 for a database which is in 2008.
I am having issues in deploying the database as I don't know why, but at the time of deployment in some procedures

`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is set to OFF`

But I intended to switch in ON at the time of deployment.

1. Is there is any setting from which I can control `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` settings in my database project?.
2. Is there any place within database project from where i can switch it on by default at the time of creation or altering..?

Answer (score 4):

`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is a connect-specific setting.  You can see what sessions have it set through the `sys.dm_exec_sessions` DMV.

But if you are looking to set the default of the instance, you can configure this through `sp_configure`:

```
exec sys.sp_configure 'user options', 256
go
reconfigure with override
go
```

See [this BOL reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190763.aspx) on user options config.

To set this on the database level, you would do:

```
alter database YourDB
set quoted_identifier on
go
```

[BOL reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx)

Within *Visual Studio 2010*, the option can be found under ***Properties*** -> **Database.sqlsettings**.  Below is a screenshot showing the option:

[image]